# ElasticSearch index works from REST API, but not C# code

Tags: c#, elasticsearch, geolocation, nest

I am trying to index data that includes geopoints in Elastic Search. When I index via code, it fails. When I index via the REST endpoints, it succeeds. But I cannot find a difference between the JSON I send via the REST endpoint, and the JSON sent when using code.

Here is the code to configure the index (as a LINQPad program):

```
async Task Main()
{
    var pool = new SingleNodeConnectionPool(new Uri("http://localhost:9200"));
    var connectionSettings = new ConnectionSettings(pool)
        .DefaultMappingFor<DataEntity>(m => m.IndexName("data").TypeName("_doc"));

    var client = new ElasticClient(connectionSettings);

    await client.CreateIndexAsync(
        "data",
        index => index.Mappings(mappings => mappings.Map<DataEntity>(mapping => mapping.AutoMap().Properties(
            properties => properties.GeoPoint(field => field.Name(x => x.Location))))));

//    var data = new DataEntity(new GeoLocationEntity(50, 30));
//            
//    var json = client.RequestResponseSerializer.SerializeToString(data);
//    json.Dump("JSON");
//            
//    var indexResult = await client.IndexDocumentAsync(data);
//    indexResult.DebugInformation.Dump("Debug Information");
}

public sealed class GeoLocationEntity
{
    [JsonConstructor]
    public GeoLocationEntity(
        double latitude,
        double longitude)
    {
        this.Latitude = latitude;
        this.Longitude = longitude;
    }

    [JsonProperty("lat")]
    public double Latitude { get; }

    [JsonProperty("lon")]
    public double Longitude { get; }
}

public sealed class DataEntity
{
    [JsonConstructor]
    public DataEntity(
        GeoLocationEntity location)
    {
        this.Location = location;
    }

    [JsonProperty("location")]
    public GeoLocationEntity Location { get; }
}
```

After running this, my mapping looks correct because `GET /data/_doc/_mapping` returns:

```
{
  "data" : {
    "mappings" : {
      "_doc" : {
        "properties" : {
          "location" : {
            "type" : "geo_point"
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

I can successfully add documents to the index via the dev console:

```
POST /data/_doc
{
  "location": {
    "lat": 88.59,
    "lon": -98.87
  }
}
```

Results in:

```
{
  "_index" : "data",
  "_type" : "_doc",
  "_id" : "RqpyjGgBZ27KOduFRIxL",
  "_version" : 1,
  "result" : "created",
  "_shards" : {
    "total" : 2,
    "successful" : 1,
    "failed" : 0
  },
  "_seq_no" : 0,
  "_primary_term" : 1
}
```

But when I uncomment the code in the LINQPad program above and execute, I get this error when indexing:

```
Invalid NEST response built from a unsuccessful low level call on POST: /data/_doc
# Audit trail of this API call:
 - [1] BadResponse: Node: http://localhost:9200/ Took: 00:00:00.0159927
# OriginalException: Elasticsearch.Net.ElasticsearchClientException: The remote server returned an error: (400) Bad Request.. Call: Status code 400 from: POST /data/_doc. ServerError: Type: mapper_parsing_exception Reason: "failed to parse" CausedBy: "Type: parse_exception Reason: "field must be either [lat], [lon] or [geohash]"" ---> System.Net.WebException: The remote server returned an error: (400) Bad Request.
   at System.Net.HttpWebRequest.EndGetResponse(IAsyncResult asyncResult)
   at Elasticsearch.Net.HttpWebRequestConnection.<>c__DisplayClass5_0`1.<RequestAsync>b__1(IAsyncResult r)
   at System.Threading.Tasks.TaskFactory`1.FromAsyncCoreLogic(IAsyncResult iar, Func`2 endFunction, Action`1 endAction, Task`1 promise, Boolean requiresSynchronization)
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ValidateEnd(Task task)
   at Elasticsearch.Net.HttpWebRequestConnection.<RequestAsync>d__5`1.MoveNext()
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
# Request:
<Request stream not captured or already read to completion by serializer. Set DisableDirectStreaming() on ConnectionSettings to force it to be set on the response.>
# Response:
<Response stream not captured or already read to completion by serializer. Set DisableDirectStreaming() on ConnectionSettings to force it to be set on the response.>
```

The dumped JSON looks like this:

```
{
  "location": {
    "latitude": 50.0,
    "longitude": 30.0
  }
}
```

So it matches the structure of the JSON that *works* from the dev console.

To move past this problem, I wrote a custom `JsonConverter` that serializes my `GeoLocationEntity` objects in the format `{lat},{lon}`:

```
public sealed class GeoLocationConverter : JsonConverter
{
    public override bool CanConvert(Type objectType) =>
        objectType == typeof(GeoLocationEntity);

    public override object ReadJson(JsonReader reader, Type objectType, object existingValue, JsonSerializer serializer)
    {
        var token = JToken.Load(reader);

        if (!(token is JValue))
        {
            throw new JsonSerializationException("Token was not a primitive.");
        }

        var stringValue = (string)token;
        var split = stringValue.Split(',');
        var latitude = double.Parse(split[0]);
        var longitude = double.Parse(split[1]);

        return new GeoLocationEntity(latitude, longitude);
    }

    public override void WriteJson(JsonWriter writer, object value, JsonSerializer serializer)
    {
        var geoLocation = (GeoLocationEntity)value;

        if (geoLocation == null)
        {
            writer.WriteNull();
            return;
        }

        var geoLocationValue = $"{geoLocation.Latitude},{geoLocation.Longitude}";
        writer.WriteValue(geoLocationValue);
    }
}
```

Applying this `JsonConverter` to the serializer settings got me past the issue. However, I don't want to hack around the problem like this.

Can anyone enlighten me as to how to solve this?

Answer (score 6):

The 6.x Elasticsearch high level client, NEST, internalized the Json.NET dependency by

- IL-merging Json.NET assembly
- converting all types to `internal`
- renamespacing them under `Nest.*`

What this means in practice is that the client does not have a direct dependency on Json.NET (have a read of the [release blog post](https://www.elastic.co/blog/nest-elasticsearch-net-6-0-ga) to understand why we did this) and does not know about Json.NET types, including `JsonPropertyAttribute` or `JsonConverter`.

There are several ways of solving this. To begin, the following setup may be helpful during development

```cs
var defaultIndex = "default-index";
var pool = new SingleNodeConnectionPool(new Uri("http://localhost:9200"));

var settings = new ConnectionSettings(pool)
    .DefaultMappingFor<DataEntity>(m => m
        .IndexName(defaultIndex)
        .TypeName("_doc")
    )
    .DisableDirectStreaming()
    .PrettyJson()
    .OnRequestCompleted(callDetails =>
    {
        if (callDetails.RequestBodyInBytes != null)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(
                $"{callDetails.HttpMethod} {callDetails.Uri} \n" +
                $"{Encoding.UTF8.GetString(callDetails.RequestBodyInBytes)}");
        }
        else
        {
            Console.WriteLine($"{callDetails.HttpMethod} {callDetails.Uri}");
        }

        Console.WriteLine();

        if (callDetails.ResponseBodyInBytes != null)
        {
            Console.WriteLine($"Status: {callDetails.HttpStatusCode}\n" +
                     $"{Encoding.UTF8.GetString(callDetails.ResponseBodyInBytes)}\n" +
                     $"{new string('-', 30)}\n");
        }
        else
        {
            Console.WriteLine($"Status: {callDetails.HttpStatusCode}\n" +
                     $"{new string('-', 30)}\n");
        }
    });

var client = new ElasticClient(settings);
```

This will write all requests and responses out to the console, so you can see what the client is sending and receiving from Elasticsearch. `.DisableDirectStreaming()` buffers the request and response bytes in memory, to make them available to the delegate passed to `.OnRequestCompleted()`, so it's useful for development but you'll probably don't want it in production as it comes at a performance cost.

Now, the solutions:

#### 1. Use `PropertyNameAttribute`

Instead of using `JsonPropertyAttribute`, you can use `PropertyNameAttribute` to name the properties for serialization

```cs
public sealed class GeoLocationEntity
{
    public GeoLocationEntity(
        double latitude,
        double longitude)
    {
        this.Latitude = latitude;
        this.Longitude = longitude;
    }

    [PropertyName("lat")]
    public double Latitude { get; }

    [PropertyName("lon")]
    public double Longitude { get; }
}

public sealed class DataEntity
{
    public DataEntity(
        GeoLocationEntity location)
    {
        this.Location = location;
    }

    [PropertyName("location")]
    public GeoLocationEntity Location { get; }
}
```

and to use

```
if (client.IndexExists(defaultIndex).Exists)
    client.DeleteIndex(defaultIndex);


var createIndexResponse = client.CreateIndex(defaultIndex, c => c 
    .Mappings(m => m
        .Map<DataEntity>(mm => mm
            .AutoMap()
            .Properties(p => p
                .GeoPoint(g => g
                    .Name(n => n.Location)
                )
            )
        )
    )
);

var indexResponse = client.Index(
    new DataEntity(new GeoLocationEntity(88.59, -98.87)), 
    i => i.Refresh(Refresh.WaitFor)
);

var searchResponse = client.Search<DataEntity>(s => s
    .Query(q => q
        .MatchAll()
    )
);
```

`PropertyNameAttribute` acts similarly to how you would normally use `JsonPropertAttribute` with Json.NET.

#### 2. Use `DataMemberAttribute`

This will work the same as `PropertyNameAttribute` in this instance, if you'd prefer your POCOs to not be attributed with NEST types (although I'd argue that the POCOs are tied to Elasticsearch, so tying them to .NET Elasticsearch types is probably not an issue).

#### 3. Use `Geolocation` type

You could replace `GeoLocationEntity` type with Nest's `GeoLocation` type, that maps to `geo_point` field datatype mapping. In using this, it's one less POCO, and the correct mapping can be inferred from the property type

```cs
public sealed class DataEntity
{
    public DataEntity(
        GeoLocation location)
    {
        this.Location = location;
    }

    [DataMember(Name = "location")]
    public GeoLocation Location { get; }
}

// ---

if (client.IndexExists(defaultIndex).Exists)
    client.DeleteIndex(defaultIndex);

var createIndexResponse = client.CreateIndex(defaultIndex, c => c 
    .Mappings(m => m
        .Map<DataEntity>(mm => mm
            .AutoMap()
        )
    )
);

var indexResponse = client.Index(
    new DataEntity(new GeoLocation(88.59, -98.87)), 
    i => i.Refresh(Refresh.WaitFor)
);

var searchResponse = client.Search<DataEntity>(s => s
    .Query(q => q
        .MatchAll()
    )
);
```

#### 4. Hooking up JsonNetSerializer

NEST allows a [custom serializer to be hooked up](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/client/net-api/current/custom-serialization.html), to take care of serializing your types. A separate nuget package, [NEST.JsonNetSerializer](https://www.nuget.org/packages/NEST.JsonNetSerializer/), allows you to use Json.NET to serialize your types, with the serializer delegating back to the internal serializer for properties that are NEST types.

First, you need to pass the JsonNetSerializer into `ConnectionSettings` constructor

```
var settings = new ConnectionSettings(pool, JsonNetSerializer.Default)
```

Then your original code will work as expected, without the custom `JsonConverter`

```cs
public sealed class GeoLocationEntity
{
    public GeoLocationEntity(
        double latitude,
        double longitude)
    {
        this.Latitude = latitude;
        this.Longitude = longitude;
    }

    [JsonProperty("lat")]
    public double Latitude { get; }

    [JsonProperty("lon")]
    public double Longitude { get; }
}

public sealed class DataEntity
{
    public DataEntity(
        GeoLocationEntity location)
    {
        this.Location = location;
    }

    [JsonProperty("location")]
    public GeoLocationEntity Location { get; }
}


// ---

if (client.IndexExists(defaultIndex).Exists)
    client.DeleteIndex(defaultIndex);


var createIndexResponse = client.CreateIndex(defaultIndex, c => c 
    .Mappings(m => m
        .Map<DataEntity>(mm => mm
            .AutoMap()
            .Properties(p => p
                .GeoPoint(g => g
                    .Name(n => n.Location)
                )
            )
        )
    )
);

var indexResponse = client.Index(
    new DataEntity(new GeoLocationEntity(88.59, -98.87)), 
    i => i.Refresh(Refresh.WaitFor)
);

var searchResponse = client.Search<DataEntity>(s => s
    .Query(q => q
        .MatchAll()
    )
);
```

I listed this option last because internally, there is a performance and allocation overhead in handing off serialization to Json.NET in this manner. It is included to provide flexibility, but I would advocate using it only when you really need to, for example, complete custom serialization of a POCO where the serialized structure is not conventional. We're working on much faster serialization that will see this overhead diminish in the future.

Comment: PropertyNameAttribute save my day!!